# Transform not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, user-interface, sdk

I am trying to rotate an object around it's current position,

```
CGAffineTransform trans =   CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(compass_heading );
trans = CGAffineTransformTranslate(trans, 0, 90);
sun_image.transform = trans;
```

But it has no effect and **sun_image** doesn't move!
But if I change it to this and translate on X axis it moves! What does this mean?

```
CGAffineTransform trans =   CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(compass_heading );
trans = CGAffineTransformTranslate(trans, 90, 0);
sun_image.transform = trans;
```

Comment: Are any autolayout or auto-sizing options set for the image view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can rotate an object:

```
    CGFloat rotation = M_PI_2;

    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = sun_image.transform;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransform,rotation);

    [sun_image setTransform:newTransform];
```

With `CGAffineTransformTranslate` you can move an object, so you must use `CGAffineTransformRotate`.

For  location manager :

```
-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{     
     //set the anchorPoint as the lower right corner of the layer
     sun_image.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1);

     [sun_image.layer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-1*newHeading.trueHeading*3.14159/180)];
}
```

Comment: But I need to rotate it when compass sensor changes, so sun_image.transform changes all the time, then what should I do?

Comment: if you are doing it with location manager do it like in my answer

Comment: I need to rotate it around screen center, so I rotate it first then translate as of radius of my circle, but it doesn't translate in first step.

Comment: you need to move and rotate?, please be explicit in your question , now we're moving to a different answer.

Comment: It's great, but sun_image is small and not centered on screen, I need to rotate it around view center, not it's self center

Comment: then why aren't you placing it in the center in the first place?

Comment: then you need to set the anchorPoint of the layer

Comment: (1,1) is the point which will rotate the view around it's lower right corner

Comment: No problem, next time explain the problem better. :)

Answer (score 1):

I generally do this for translation transforms:

```
sun_image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(dx,dy);
```

Answer (score 1):

First set center of your `UIImageView` with your view center property like bellow..

```
yourImageView.center = self.view.center;
```

after set `GestureRecognizer` like bellow..

```
    UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];
    [rotationRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [yourImageView addGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];
    [rotationRecognizer release];
```

and then use this bellow method for rotate `UIImageView`

```
-(void)rotate:(id)sender 
{
    UIView *imgTempGest = [sender view];

    if([(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) 
    {
        lastRotation = 0.0;
        return;
    }
    CGFloat rotation = 0.0 - (lastRotation - [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender rotation]);

    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view].transform;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransform,rotation);

    [[(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender view] setTransform:newTransform];

    [imgTempGest setTransform:newTransform];

    lastRotation = [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender rotation];
}
```

take `lastRotation` variable of `CGFloat` like bellow..

```
CGFloat lastRotation;
```